# Equivalent to jQuery - .one() in Prototype?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Anyone knows the alternative of `.one()` in Prototype please ?

**JQUERY FUNCTION**

```
$("img").one('load', function() {
   // do stuff
}).each(function() {
   if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
$$("img").each(function(i) {
    var handler = i.on("load", function() {
        handler.stop();
        // do stuff
    });
    // other stuff
});
```